# ScrollView constraint doesn't scrolls if soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I'm using a Constaint layout for a login screen which contains a some EditTextView.I have tried many types of fixes but cant seem to get one working. I would like to be able to scroll through my page when an editText is selected and the keyboard takes up half the screen.i added "thisandroid:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to my mainfest file but i still have the same problem.
this my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.activities.NewAccount" >




    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/coversignup"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <com.etc.abdlhadi_etc.pro_latrattoria_android.utilites.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="237dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/dore"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            android:text="Créer votre compte"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="357dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Nom"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="357dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="357dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Mot de passe"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tel"
            android:layout_width="357dp"
            android:layout_height="47dp"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Tél"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup"
            android:layout_width="353dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Créer votre compte"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/dore"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tel" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not using a fullscreen layout? adjustResize won't work with fullscreens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a bug in ConstraintLayout implementation. I've reported it in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69412650).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it's working as intended. The layout is incompressible the way it's defined -- what exactly do you expect to resize? adjustPan seems a better solution here. When I try it, it scrolls correctly to the textfield when the keyboard shows up.